# Alternative of "oneOf" construct in OpenApi 2.0 JSON

Tags: swagger, openapi, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I am trying to create a JSON that will be parsed with OpenApi 2.0 swagger definition in Microsoft Power Automate Custom connector.

This is the JSON i have currently

```
"connectionParameters" : {
    "param1" : "value1",
    "param2" : "value2"
}
```

I want to provide an alternative connection parameter schema, in which user has the option to choose from a set of params to provide value. This can be achieved in OpenAPI 3.0 in the following way:

```
"connectionParameters" : {
    anyOf : [
    {
      "param1" : "value1",
      "param2" : "value2"
    },
    {
      "alternateparam1" : "value1",
      "alternateparam2" : "value2"
    }
   ]
}
```

How can this be achieved in OpenAPI 2.0? "anyOf" is not available in OpenAPI 2.0 definition. I have explored the "discriminator" construct but couldn't find any implementation that I can provide with my JSON schema.

Comment: So if break it down, do you just want the ability for the user to select from a predefined list of values? Is that right?

Comment: Yes @Skin, I have two possible sets of values. I want user to select one of the sets and provide all the values in that set.

Comment: Do you control the endpoint behind the API definition?

Comment: Yes we control the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the approach you're trying with v3.0 would be a little confusing for the end user as I don't really understand what they'd actually be selecting in a dropdown persay.

I think your best bet (given you're limited anyway) is to use the `ENUM` keyword to define a basic list of values that when selected and passed into your API, you do the work in the background to select the more advanced objects that you've listed in your question.

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/